# Access value of each iterated item bash

Tags: linux, bash, files

I have code that traverses a directory, and finds all the files with a `.xz` extension

The problem is I cannot seem to figure out how to access each iterated file with `.xz` instead i get the value of `ROOTPATH` . what am i doing wrong?

```
ROOTPATH='/home/user/path'
for file in "$ROOTPATH"; do
find $PWD -name '*.xz'
echo "file is $file"
done
```

This outputs the files like:

```
/home/user/path/file1.tar.xz
/home/user/path/file2.tar.xz
```

then the `echo` portion prints:

```
file is /home/user/path
```

how can i access each of the iterated items, e.g.

```
/home/user/path/file1.tar.xz
/home/user/path/file2.tar.xz
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the glob `*.xz` to match the files in the path, when you do this, you don't even need the `find` command. Just do

```
ROOTPATH="/home/user/path"
for file in "$ROOTPATH"/*.xz; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

The `*.xz` is a standard glob pattern to match all files with `.xz` extension in the path specified. The `[ -f "$file" ] || continue` is just a sanity check needed for gracefully handling the loop exit when the glob returns an empty result i.e. when no files are found.

If in by chance you are looking for files under the sub-directories also, enable the extended shell globbing option `globstar` to enable recursive match on the filenames and do

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in "$ROOTPATH"/**/*.xz; do
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

Comment: This will only search the ROOTPATH directory, but not subdirectories...

Comment: @JaroslavKucera: Yeah! OP didn't post that requirement though. The question just says on the path provided

Comment: I mean't subdirs. Btw, this returns nothing.. no errors

Comment: @johnjones: It worked fine for me! Which one did you try? The first or the second part? in the case of the latter, don't forget to enable the options included as `shopt`

Answer (score 1):

You should not iterate over the result of `find`, see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Instead, call your script from within `find`:

```bash
find "$ROOTPATH" -type f -name '*.xz' \
    -exec sh -c 'for n; do printf "Got name %s\n" "$n"; done' sh {} +
```

or, to call a separate script:

```bash
find "$ROOTPATH" -type f -name '*.xz' \
    -exec /some/path/script.sh {} +
```

The script could look like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for name; do
    # do something with "$name"
done
```

The script, whether embedded with `sh -c` (or `bash -c` if you need `bash`) or separate, will in this case be called with as many `.xz` files as possible (it may be called several times if the number of files are in the hundreds).  The `for name` loop will iterate over the found names and you can use `$name` (properly quoted, of course) to do whatever it is you need to do to the individual files.

Answer (score 0):

Use find in the for cycle itself:

```
ROOTPATH="/home/user/path"
for file in `find $ROOTPATH -type f -name *.xz -print`
do
        echo "file is $file"
done
```